# Why does this code generate the error 'undefined reference to main' upon compilation?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

This is for an assignment, but right now I'm just playing around with a code I found in a tutorial, but I can't seem to get it to compile, and I don't understand the error I receive. My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *myfunc (void *myvar);

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    char *msg1 = "First thread";
    char *msg2 = "Second thread";
    int ret1;
    int ret2;
    //create threads
    ret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, myfunc, (void*) msg1);
    ret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, myfunc, (void*) msg2);

    printf("Main function after pthread_create\n");
    //join threads back to main process once completed
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    printf("Return thread ret1 = %d\n", ret1);
    printf("Return thread ret2 = %d\n", ret2);


    return 0;
}

void *myfunc(void *myvar)

{
    char *msg;
    msg = (char *) myvar;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s%d\n", msg, i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I compiled using `gcc -o c_thread c_thread.c`
and received the error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/.../.../.../x84_64-linux-gnu/ctr1.o: In function '_start':
/build/buildd/glibc-2.21/csu/.../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:114: undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know other questions have been asked about similar errors, but every answer I found related to a code which used a 'nontraditional' main function, whereas mine follows the standard `int main(int argc char *argv[])` format

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Since you're following a tutorial, ensure the file you're compiling is the one you're actually editing! - that error message is seen when the file is empty, too

Comment: The code you have posted here is ok, and will not show the error you claim it does under normal circumstances. So you need to verify that's the actual code you're trying to compile, or if there's something peculiar about your environment or platform you should tell us about it.

Comment: U forget to link the POSIX library in your code. It will compile your code `gcc -o c_thread c_thread.c -lpthread`

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the -lpthread when compiling

Try compiling as following via terminal or adjusting the settings from the linker if you're working in an IDE:

> gcc pro.c -o pro -lpthread

Suppose pro.c was your program file.

Comment: The error seems to be about `main` not being found, not about `pthread` not being found.

Comment: I compiled it with gcc on my ubuntu pc and recieved no error. It's probably how he's calling gcc.